# PHP: Display Session variable in View: CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

As mention in the title I am trying to send the Session variables in the View Section after I login,
The Session contains let's say `name` and `email`.

So what I have tried in the Profile Controller Section is below:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller{
public function index()
{ 
    $session = session();

    $userDetails = ['name' => $session->get('name'),
                     'email' => $session->get('email')];
    print_r($userDetails);
    echo view('profile', $userDetails); 
}
```

}

although I am able to print the `$userDetails` value in the controller Section, the same I am trying in `VIEW` is giving me nothing.

here's my `profile.php` code in view.

```
<h3>Welcome to the Profile Section : <?php echo $userDetails['name']; ?></h3>
<p>Your email id : <?php echo $userDetails['email'] ; ?></p>
```

The output I am getting is :

[image: Result Image]

Please correct me if I am missing something as I am new to the PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View you would just have the array named indexes as they are converted to variables.

So `$userDetails['name']` becomes `$name` and
`$userDetails['email']` becomes `$email`

So in your case.
Instead of

```
<h3>Welcome to the Profile Section : <?php echo $userDetails['name']; ?></h3>
<p>Your email id : <?php echo $userDetails['email'] ; ?></p>
```

You would have.

```
<h3>Welcome to the Profile Section : <?php echo $name; ?></h3>
<p>Your email id : <?php echo $email ; ?></p>
```

And you can replace `<?php echo` with the shorter version `<?=`

```
<h3>Welcome to the Profile Section : <?= $name; ?></h3>
<p>Your email id : <?= $email ; ?></p>
```

I would strongly suggest to read the CodeIgniter Userguide as it covers this and everything else the framework does. So it's good to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **compact** function support by laravel to make array from your variable, and return a View you want

```
 return view('profile', compact('name','mail'));
```

At view you can call it by {{$name}} like this:

```
 <h3>Welcome to the Profile Section : {{$name}}></h3>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. but the question I asked was for codeigniter framework, I don't know that the above code will work for it though.

Comment: The answer offers quite a framework agnostic way of doing things. Also, mind the way you render your view — the proper way might differ from what you do (e.g. `return view` or `$this->load->view` instead of `echo view`)

Comment: as I am loading multiple views in the controller, let's say header, body and footer. the `return view` is returning only header view. and `$this->load->view()` is giving error in CodeIgniter4. That's why I have used `echo view()` @EduardSukharev